# I am multilingual in flutter gen-l10n and would like to multilingualize the app name and permission requests in info.plist

Tags: flutter, flutter-localizations

I am multilingual in flutter gen-l10n and would like to multilingualize the app name and permission requests in info.plist.

- reject detail

```
We noticed an issue in your app that contributes to a lower-quality user experience than App Store users expect:

- Your app's permissions requests are written in English while the app is set to the Japanese localization. To help users understand why your app is requesting access to a specific feature, your app's permission requests should be in the same language as your app's current localization.
```

- pubspec.yaml

```
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.19.6 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter

  intl: ^0.18.1
  app_tracking_transparency: ^2.0.4

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  true
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the list of languages your app supports in the `Info.plist` file under the `CFBundleLocalizations` property.

There might be a case where the languages supported by your app is not present in the iOS system preferred languages list and it leads to multiple languages appearing in the app during runtime. This might be a potential Apple review reject reason.